# Solving double integration in python using scipy.integrate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to compute this integral:

[image]

I have a data file providing values of cos(theta), phi and g.

I am trying to solve it using the trapezoid method of `scipy.integrate`. But I am unsure if this is the correct way since it is a double integration and g depends on both cos_theta and phi.

The code is as follows :

```
nvz = 256
nph = 256
dOmega = (2.0/nvz) * (2*np.pi / nph)
dphi = (2*np.pi / nph)
dtheta = (2.0/nvz)
cos_theta = file[:,0]
sin_theta = np.sqrt(1-cos_theta**2)
phi = file[:,1]
cos_phi = np.cos(phi)
sin_phi = np.sin(phi)
g = file[:,2]

integrate.trapezoid(sin_theta*cos_phi*g, dx = dOmega)
```

Can someone please suggest me a way to solve it correctly?

Comment: This isn't a double integral. It is one integral multiplied by a second integral. You can take $\sin(\theta)$ out of the second integral.

Comment: When you extract `file[:, 0]`, what is the shape of the resulting array?

Comment: @MarkBakker no you cannot do that. notice that its not $\sin(\theta) d\theta$ but rather its $d\sin(\theta)$

Comment: @MattHaberland The shape of the resulting array is (65536,1).

Comment: @MarkBakker I understand that but g is actually a function of both \theta and \phi. Obviously here it is just a number.

Comment: Ok, that's 256**2. It may or may not matter much in practice, but the trapezoidal rule gives less weight to the function values at the lower and upper limits of integration. If you want to use `trapezoid` correctly, you need to reshape those long 1D arrays into 2D arrays of shape (256, 256) where `dphi` increases along one axis and `dtheta` increases along thr other. Then you can follow something like my original answer, which I'm undeleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scipy.integrate.trapezoid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.trapezoid.html#scipy.integrate.trapezoid) is for 1D integrals. If you have a 2D integral, you'd need to integrate over each axis of your array separately.

Since I don't have your data file, I will also need to generate the data. In particular, I'll assume `g = (costh + phi)**2`, but it can be any function.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

nvz = 2560  # I'll evaluate at more points just to see closer
nph = 2560  # agreement with quadrature

dphi = (2*np.pi / nph)
dtheta = (2.0/nvz)

# align `costh` along axis 0 and `phi` along axis 1
costh = np.linspace(-1, 1, nvz)[:, np.newaxis]
phi = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, nph)[np.newaxis, :]

# g can be any array broadcastable to shape `(nvz, nph)`
g = (phi + costh)**2

# integrate along axis 1, then integrate along remaining axis
sinth = np.sqrt(1 - costh**2)
integrand = sinth * np.cos(phi) * g
int_phi = integrate.trapezoid(integrand, dx=dphi, axis=1)
res = integrate.trapezoid(int_phi, dx=dtheta, axis=0)
res  # -19.72363915277977
```

Compare against:

```py
def integrand(phi, costh):
    sinth = np.sqrt(1 - costh**2)
    g = (phi + costh)**2
    return sinth * np.cos(phi) * g

integrate.dblquad(integrand, -1, 1, -np.pi, np.pi)
# (-19.73920880217874, 1.2569373097903735e-08)
```

Note that you could also use `integrate.simpson` as a drop-in replacement for `integrate.trapezoid`.